# ITunes album artwork is not ready for retina display! how to solve that?

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, itunes-sdk

I'm developign an app that display the image from itunes store album covers, and the biggest immage available in the itunes api is 100x100 image which sux in the retina display off couse...unless I subtract by 2 the image size, which I don't wnat to....

https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=211192863&entity=song

http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/040/Music/21/58/3e/dj.bxwywnxk.100x100-75.jpg

I notived there is retina image available in the itunes app in the iphone, but this source is not available in the api...

how do I solve that? I would hate to have to scrape itunes app web interface to get that image istead of using itunes search api

Edit:

I really believe this is a mistake from apple not providing a bigger size for retina display.... trying to figure out what to do now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Apple doesn't return these images, you should be able to retrieve the 225px and 600px versions of the artwork for standard screens, and 450px and 1200px for retina displays. Just replace 100 with the desired resolution. For example:

http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/040/Music/21/58/3e/dj.bxwywnxk.225x225-75.jpg

http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/040/Music/21/58/3e/dj.bxwywnxk.450x450-75.jpg

http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/040/Music/21/58/3e/dj.bxwywnxk.600x600-75.jpg

http://a5.mzstatic.com/us/r1000/040/Music/21/58/3e/dj.bxwywnxk.1200x1200-75.jpg